# avoiding circular includes while retaining desired functionality and not making extra declarations

Tags: c, header-files

I have implemented a generic typed-value with a struct storing the datatype as an enum and a the value as a union in `type.c` with declarations in `type.h`. For each some typed-values, there are ways to add them (like doubles, ints, polynomials, etc). I have implemented a function in `type.c`
two add two typed-values with its declaration in `type.h`. All this function does is calls the type specific function to add the two typed values from elsewhere.

For instance I have  I have declared a datatype for a polynomial along with a function to add polynomials in `polynomial.h` /`polynomial.c`.

Now I would like to treat polynomial as its own type. From what I have gathered reading other posts about circular include statements, I would need to declare this polynomial struct and its add function in `type.h`/`type.c` to avoid any problems. I was wondering if there is a another way, since having to declare/define structs and functions in `type.h`/`type.c` would defeat the purpose of having a lot of polynomial related things being declared/defined in `polynomial.h`/`polynomial.c`

```
// type.h

#ifndef TYPE_H
#define TYPE_H

typedef enum dtype dtype; 
typedef union value value;
typedef struct tvalue tvalue;

enum dtype {
    // double
    DBL,
    // PLY, // would like to have a PLY type here
};

union value {
    double dblval;
  //Polynomial polyval;  // would like to have polynomial type here
};

struct tvalue {
    dtype type;
    value val;
};

// if type poly, would like to call ply_add
t_sum(tvalue a, tvalue b, tvalue sum);
```

```
// polynomial.h

typedef struct Polynomial Polynomial;

struct Polynomial {
    dtype type; 
    int deg;
    tvalue *coefs;
};

void ply_add(Polynomial *p1, Polynomial *p2, Polynomial *sum);
```

Comment: Don't really understand your problem but .. `t_sum(tvalue a, tvalue b, tvalue sum);` is wrong

Comment: If you don't want to modify type.h every time you create a new type, how would the stuff in type.h know all the types it should define.  I think you need to declare something ahead of time that knows what all of the types are.  How this is normally handled is to have something in the build process that creates type.h on the fly - kind of like how flex and bison work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things you need to do:

1. Forward declare `Polynomial` in types.h
2. types in types.h can use a pointer to a `Polynomail`
3. `#include` types.h then polynomial.h inside types.c
4. `#include` types.h in polynomail.h

explanation:

1. Forward declarations tell the compiler that this type exists. It doesnt tell it how to use it though. Now you won't get errors if you reference `Polynomial`s in types.h
2. Even though it makes it a bit more difficult, you can't use a `Polynomial` inside types.h as we haven't told the compiler what that type is. However, we have said this type exists, and the compiler knows how to create a pointer. So we can create a pointer to a `Polynomial`
3. include types.h inside types.c as normal. Then include polynomial.h inside types.c to now tell the compiler what a polynomial is. At this point we are done processing types.h and so wont get circular inclusions. At this point we know the prototypes of functions inside the polynomial.c file
4. We've told the types file how to use a polynomial file, now we can tell the polynomials file how to use all the other types.

Comment: I think I understand, thanks for spelling it out for me. I think I can generalize for all the other structures that I need to do this with as well. For instance if I want a matrix type and a poly type, after doing the polynomial stuff as you mentioned above, I think I could 
1. declare matrix struct in types.h
2. include types.h in matrix.h
3. include matrix.h in types.c
and I should be able to make a matrix of polys of doubles for instance.